# Google function execution interupting for no reason using threading

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-functions, python-multithreading

I set up a very classical API with Google Cloud Function (GCF) using python 3.9. Its purpose is to be called with a link of a file as parameters, download this file, formatting its data and then insert these data into a database.
The main code is:

```
import csv
from csv import DictReader
from json import dumps
import gzip
from gzip import BadGzipFile
import io
from io import BytesIO
from threading import Thread
from typing import Optional, Any
import requests
from requests import exceptions, get
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import extras
import re
from re import search
from flask import Response, Request
from decouple import config
from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequest


def call_thread(request: Request) -> Response:
    Thread(target=main, args=(request._get_current_object(),)).start()
    return Response(
        "OK",
        status=200,
    )


def main(request: Request) -> Response:
    parameters_list = list_parameters(request.args)
    file_url, device_id = retrieve_buddy_parameters(parameters_list)
    trz_file = get_buddy_file(file_url)
    print(f"Data retrieved from source {source_type}")
    raw_csv_data = unzip_file_to_csv(trz_file)
    print("File unzipped")
    column_id = generate_column_id(raw_csv_data)
    json_data = convert_csv_to_json(raw_csv_data, column_id)
    print(threading.current_thread())
    print("CSV data cleaned and converted to JSON")
    send(json_data, device_id)
    print("Data inserted into DB")
    return Response("OK", status=200)


def list_parameters(parameters_dict: dict[str, Any]) -> list[Any]:
    return list(value for key, value in parameters_dict.items())


def retrieve_buddy_parameters(parameters_list: list[Any]) -> tuple[str, str]:
    print(parameters_list)
    if is_a_valid_url(parameters_list[0]) and is_a_non_empty_str(parameters_list[1]):
        return parameters_list[0], str(parameters_list[1])
    else:
        raise ValueError("Missing parameters")


def is_a_valid_url(url_to_verify: str) -> bool:
    return bool(search(URL_FILE_PATTERN, url_to_verify))


def is_a_non_empty_str(device_id: Any) -> bool:
    return isinstance(device_id, str) and device_id != "" and not device_id.isspace()


def get_make_file(request: Request) -> BytesIO:
    body_data = request.get_data()
    return BytesIO(body_data)


def get_buddy_file(file_url: str) -> BytesIO:
    try:
        buddy_response = get(file_url, stream=True)
    except exceptions.ConnectionError:
        raise exceptions.HTTPError(f"400, URL source file {file_url} not found")
    adrena_data = buddy_response.content
    return io.BytesIO(adrena_data)


def unzip_file_to_csv(trz_file: BytesIO) -> str:
    with gzip.open(filename=trz_file, mode="rt", encoding="cp1250") as trz_data:
        raw_csv_data = trz_data.read()
        raw_csv_data_as_str: str
        if isinstance(raw_csv_data, str):
            raw_csv_data_as_str = raw_csv_data
        else:
            raw_csv_data_as_str = raw_csv_data.decode("cp1250")
        return raw_csv_data_as_str


def generate_column_id(csv_data: str) -> list[str]:
    reader = csv.reader(str.splitlines(csv_data), delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        if row and row[0] == "$TANAV":
            column_nbr = len(row)
            break
    return [str(x) for x in range(1, column_nbr + 1)]


def convert_csv_to_json(
    raw_csv_data: str, column_id: list[str]
) -> list[dict[str, str]]:
    reader = DictReader(
        str.splitlines(raw_csv_data), fieldnames=column_id, delimiter=","
    )
    return filter_line(reader)

def filter_line(reader: Any) -> list[Any]:
    return list(
        clean_csv_line(csv_line)
        for csv_line in reader
        if csv_line and csv_line["1"] == "$TANAV"
    )


def clean_csv_line(list_to_clean: dict[str, str]) -> dict[str, str]:
    return {k: v for k, v in list_to_clean.items() if is_a_non_empty_str(v)}


def send(pos_to_send: list[dict[str, str]], device_id: str) -> None:
    values = create_item_to_send(pos_to_send, device_id)
    with psycopg2.connect(
        CONNECTION_STRING.format(DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DATABASE, DB_USER, PASSWORD)
    ) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            extras.execute_values(
                cursor, INSERT_COMMAND, values, page_size=values.__len__()
            )
            conn.commit()


def create_item_to_send(pos_to_send: list[dict[str, str]], device_id: str) -> list[Any]:
    return list(map(lambda pos: (device_id, dumps(pos)), pos_to_send))
```

Originally, I did not use the threading library and execute all the code in the same thread and there was no problem at the execution.

But later, in order to not keep waiting the caller (which is a website) during the execution time (which can take few minute in case the file is huge), I use a thread to firstly return an HTTP response, and then continue executing the code afterward (as you can see in the begin at the code).
Unfortunately, the execution in GFC goes wrong, and using the GFC logs, I saw that the code suddenly interrupting  rigth in the middle of the execution, without any error code or message, beside the one I print in the standard output:

[image: logs traceback]
After a lot of try, I determined that the code stop executing somewhere inside these lines:

```
    return list(
        clean_csv_line(csv_line)
        for csv_line in reader
        if csv_line and csv_line["1"] == "$TANAV"
    )
```

(But anyways, I don't think these lines are the specifics causes of the bug.)

After other try with a very tiny file to process, the execution goes well. So I immediately think of a memory issues, or even a timeout issue. But it seems that's it's not, because when I put the maximum settings (memory available...) of GFC it continue to interrupting the execution at the same place and anyways with the metrics shown by the console I saw that there is not a bottleneck of this type:

[image: GCF metrics]

Moreover, there is no trace of this bugs when I execute it on my computer, no matter the size of the file (and no trace of excessive memory usage)
Have you any idea about this issues, which is apparently related to threading support in GCF?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake in the serverless approach. Let me explain the concept, you will understand your issue.

With Cloud Functions, Cloud Run or App Engine (standard) you pay only with a request is served. The products scale natively to 0. When a request comes in, a new instance is created and the request served. The instance is kept idle for a while (about 30 minutes with Cloud FUnctions, 15 minutes with Cloud Run).

If a new request comes in, the already started instance serves it, and the idle timer is reset. If you have a lot of requests, the products create additional instance to absorb the traffic. And scale down according to the idle duration.

As you can see, the instances are kept warm, but you are not billed for them, you are billed only when the request is processed. It's also for that you have full CPU power during request processing, and the CPU power is throttle (below 5%) when your instance doesn't serve request (to share the CPU power with other instances).

---

Now, go back to your process. You receive a request, start a tread and return the response. From Cloud Functions point of view, the processing is over and the idle timer is started, and the CPU throttled.

To solve that, don't send the answer before the end of background processes. Be careful, the max timeout of Cloud Functions is 9 minutes to handle a request. If you need more, you can use Cloud Run -> timeout 60minutes (that also offers a min-instance option that can help you to perform that background process)

Comment: Thanks for your clear and interesting explanation, it seems indeed logic that the execution fail with a huge file. So, in the end, there is no solution in this environnement (GCF) to close quickly the http connection for the caller point of view?

Comment: If your workflow is asynchronous, use async product. For instance, you receive a request on Cloud Function, create a message in PubSub, or stack a message in Cloud Task, and then answer OK to the caller. Then unstack the messages in background. You can still use Cloud Function or Cloud Run, the principle is the same (your CPU is allowed only until you send the response), but because the caller is a Google Cloud Service (PubSub/Cloud Task) no problem for keeping the connection open.

Comment: I didn't know these google services, I will dig that.
Thanks a lot!